# Strange Pypy AttributeError

Tags: python, pypy, attributeerror

I want to use pypy to speed up my python code. But i have these strange problems.

This is my code in the init methode of a class:

```
self._parse_function_by_id_prefix = { 
        'T': self._parse_textbound_annotation,
        'M': self._parse_modifier_annotation,
        'A': self._parse_attribute_annotation,
        'N': self._parse_normalization_annotation,
        'R': self._parse_relation_annotation,
        '*': self._parse_equiv_annotation,
        'E': self._parse_event_annotation,
        'F': self._parse_textlevel_annotation,
        '#': self._parse_comment_annotation,
        }`
```

This will call the right function when needed and it's defined like this

```
def _parse_textlevel_annotation(self, _id, data, data_tail, input_file_path):
    _type, ids = data.split(' ')
    ids = ids.split(';')
    return TextLevelAnnotation(_id,_type,ids,data_tail.strip())

def _parse_textbound_annotation(self, _id, data, data_tail, input_file_path):
    _type, spans = self._split_textbound_data(_id, data, input_file_path)
    return TextBoundAnnotation(spans, _id, _type, data_tail, source_id=input_file_path)
```

When i try to run this with "pypy filename" i get an AttributeError for _parse_textbound_annotation and only this one, the others don't give an error.
When i use the normal compiler it works just fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel
  File "annotation.py", line 2132, in <module>
    ann = TextAnnotations("/home/hast/Downloads/brat/data/brat_vb/sentiment/test")
  File "annotation.py", line 1059, in __init__
    Annotations.__init__(self, document, read_only)
  File "annotation.py", line 330, in __init__
    'F': self._parse_textlevel_annotation,
AttributeError: 'TextAnnotations' object has no attribute '_parse_textlevel_annotation'
```

I also had an other strange NameError because a global name wasn't defined but that got fixed by simply retyping it.

Comment: What are the exact error messages? Post the full tracebacks.

Comment: "but that got fixed by simply retyping it." -- Are you sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces?  (use `python -t filename` to check)

Comment: Indentation problems seem plausible here. If you accidentally dedented `_parse_textlevel_annotation` outside the `class` definition, everything would compile perfectly well, but you'd end up defining a global function `_parse_textlevel_annotation` instead of a method `_parse_textlevel_annotation`, so `self. _parse_textlevel_annotation` would raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @abarnert -- That's the only hypothesis I could come up with..

Comment: @mgilson: Well, he could be using an early 2.0 alpha and needs to upgrade to 2.0 beta or later, or he could have some Unicode character in the name that looks like a lowercase Latin letter but isn't and some coding declaration that makes everything work in CPython but that PyPy doesn't understand, or… but yeah, your hypothesis seems the most likely.

Comment: @mgilson indeed, that solved the problem. I only started learning Python recently, never knew tabs shouldn't be used. Thanks

Comment: Do you still have the source code of an example that behaves differently on PyPy and with regular Python?  Because that would show a bug in PyPy, even if it's on some strange case of mixing tabs and spaces.